# Showing that $\mathfrak{a}$ is a projective $S$-module which is not free

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, homological-algebra

**Problem:** Let $R$ be a non-trivial ring and let $S = R \oplus R$. Show that $\mathfrak{a} = \left\{ (0, r) \mid r \in R \right\}$ is a projective $S$-module which is not free.

**Attempt:** I know that free $R$-modules are projective. Now $R$ as an $R$-module is free, so that $S = R \oplus R$ is free, and hence projective. But a submodule of a projective module need not necessarily be projective.

So I don't know how to show that $\mathfrak{a}$ is projective.

That it is not free as an $S$-module, is clear from this I believe: a basis would consist of $\left\{ (0, 1 ) \right\}$. But then $(1,0) \cdot (0, 1) = (0, 0)$ while the coefficient is non-zero.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know the characterization of projective modules as those which are direct summands of free modules? That should help you show that $\mathfrak{a}$ is projective. As for showing that $\mathfrak{a}$ is not free, your proof is incomplete but has the right idea. You can't just show that a particular spanning set is not a basis. On the other hand, your proof shows that every element $x \in \mathfrak{a}$ admits a nonzero $s \in S$ such that $sx = 0$, and so every nonempty subset $X \subset \mathfrak{a}$ is $S$-linearly dependent.

Comment: You mean this: An $R$-module $M$ is projective if there exists another $R$-module $N$ such that $M \otimes N$ is a free $R$-module? Yes I know this, but not sure how it can help me. I would say $\mathfrak{a} \oplus R \cong R \oplus R$, and since $S$ is projective, so is $\mathfrak{a}$.

Comment: You have not proved it is not free; you have just proved that $\{(0,1)\}$ is not a basis.  There might be a different basis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that $\mathfrak{a}$ is projective you need to find another module so that the direct sum of the two is free.
Let me write $\mathfrak{b} = \{(r,0) \:|\: r \in R\}$, then we have $S = \mathfrak{a} \oplus \mathfrak{b}$ and so $\mathfrak{a}$ is a direct summand of $S$ which is free as $S$-module and hence $\mathfrak{a}$ is projective.

By the way, it is true that submodules of projective modules do not have to be projective, however, direct summands of projective modules are projective (this is an easy exercise).

To show that $\mathfrak{a}$ is not a free $S$-module, it suffices to show that $\mathfrak{a}$ is not a faithful $S$-module. In fact, it is easy to show that $Ann_S(\mathfrak{a}) = \mathfrak{b}$ whereas $Ann_S(M) = \{0\}$ for every free $S$-module $M$.

Note that a module being projective or free depends on the ring you consider. The way you phrased your attempt makes me believe that this is something you should think about a bit more: It is true that $R$ is $R$-free and thus also $R$-projective and thus $S$ is also $R$-free and $R$-projective as are $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ (as $R$-modules they are isomorphic to $R$). At the same time, $S$ is also $S$-free and $S$-projective but $\mathfrak{a}$ and $\mathfrak{b}$ are only $S$-projective and not $S$-free.